# Where to add shellescape in texstudio when using latexmk?

Tags: texstudio, latexmk, svg, shell-escape

For using svg images in pdflatex, I have to enable shell-escape. I am using texstudio and latexmk. Where to set shell-escape?

Comment: Amongst its own options latexmk also takes the options that latex does

Comment: 'latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape" %'   in options -> commands is the solution.I have figured it out!